# Custom view extends FrameLayout and TextView inside it wants to read the style set outside

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-styles

I want to design the view that has the imageView and textView. When there is image, then show the imageView. If not has image, then show textView. I want this framelayout to be circle with custom background color.

So i think about like that

```
public class CircleAvatarView extends FrameLayout {

    private CircleImageView mImageView;

    private TextView mTextView;

}
```

This is the layout inside the CircleAvatarView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <com.example.test.avatar.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</merge>
```

This is the CircleAvatarView that i use in my activity layout. Because this cycle avatar view may need different background color and text appearance setting. So i defined it in style.

```
<com.example.test.avatar.CircleAvatarView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        style="@style/CircleAvatarStyle">
    </com.example.test.avatar.CircleAvatarView>

<style name="CircleAvatarStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/avatar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

The problem comes here that i don't know how to get these textAppearance attr and set it to the internal textView.

I want to use the mTextView.setTextAppearance(context, defStyleRes); or mTextView.setTextAppearance(defStyleRes). But i can't retrieve the defStyleRes in my CircleAvatarView.

The reason i design like that is i want it to be a common widget that anyone can use if needs this feature instead of each layout itself in everywhere.

Is there any suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44993943/4797289) and set attribute in xml for CircleAvatarView

Comment: So i need to declare custom stylable , cannot use the andorid framework textappearance attribute?

Comment: you can use custom naming, example  <attr name="textSizeCustom" format="string" />

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now declare the custom attribute.